# Trike with 60+ pounds basket possible?

Tags: tricycle, basket

I noticed that many trikes have a basket in the back but I need something much stronger capable of carrying a golf cart battery which weighs about 60 pounds so is that possible to make a custom one capable of that weight or even better, capable of carrying 2 of those batteries simultaneously for 120 pounds total?  Could it just be made out of wood or is metal better?  Do you think having that much weight back there would cause any issues such as frequent flats on the rear tires unless I use super thick tubes?

Comment: Consider the load per wheel on a tandem or bakfiets with two children in. You might need to choose better tyres and inflate them harder. Be sure to secure the load.

Comment: 60 pounds, or 30 kilos should be well within the load carry capacity of a trike.     I've towed a trailer with a total weight of 101 kilos (over 200 pounds)  (and the load in the trailer was at least 95 kilos) even though it was a kiddy trailer with a rated maximum of 30 kilos.  Yes it was slow and hard work.

Comment: Consider a lithium battery rather than a hefty lump of lead in a SLA battery.  The same capacity would be about 20% of the weight, so 12 pounds not 60.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a trailer for this.  There are ready-made ones like http://www.bobgear.com/bike-trailers or you could build your own.  Then a lot of the weight can go onto a dedicated trailer wheel (or two),  which should make it no big deal to carry two 60 pound batteries (assuming you have legs of steel, obviously).

Comment: No my legs are made of skin, bones, muscle, cartilage...  no steel.  I;ll  just let the low gears do the work.  No significant hills here in central Florida where I ride, just bridges I sometimes cross.